# Execute PostGIS functions in a JpaRepository's query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgis

I have a JpaRepository like this one:

```
public interface PipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Pipe, Long> {
    @Query("select p from Pipe p where st_intersects(p.geometry, ?1)=true")
    Collection<Pipe> find(Geometry envelope);

    @Query(value = "SELECT st_extent(p.geometry) FROM Pipe p WHERE p.id IN ?1")
    Geometry getPipe(Collection<Number> id);
}
```

The first one works OK but the second one throws this exception during initialization:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'st_extent' {originalText=st_extent}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'pipe0_.geometry' {propertyName=geometry,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=geometry,path=p.geometry,tableAlias=pipe0_,className=es.x.model.Pipe,classAlias=p}
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'pipe0_.id' {alias=p, className=es.x.model.Pipe, tableAlias=pipe0_}
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'geometry' {originalText=geometry}
```

Any hint of the reason why `st_intersects` works and `st_extent` doesn't?

UPDATE: I think that the issue is with Spring Data JPA not recognizing the PostGIS functions. This aggregate function (SQL's sum) works correctly:

```
@Query("select sum(p.id) from Pipe p where p.id in ?1")
Number getPipesSum(Collection<Number> ids);
```

Comment: Check [Hibernate Spatial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and solved it as follows:

In your Spring Boot Repository interface, you can use st_astext() to receive your query results as WKT.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT st_astext(st_extent(p.geometry)) FROM Pipe p WHERE p.id IN ?1")
String getPipe(Collection<Number> id);
```

You will see that the return type is a String (which may or may not be good).

Once you have your WKT back from the database, I used org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory to convert it back into a Geometry

```
@Autowired
private GeometryFactory factory;

WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(factory);
Geometry geom = reader.read(yourReturnVariable);
```

If you look at `geom.getGeometryType()` you will see that it is a viable Geometry that you can then use in other operations.

As I said before, this may not be a *good* solution, but it does work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, because the st_extent funtion returns `box2d` dataType.

The result for the query is

**"BOX(x1 y1,x2 y2)"** , but you can cast to geometry

`SELECT st_extent(p.geometry)::geometry FROM Pipe p WHERE p.id = ?1`

Or perhaps (to avoid the use of  ::)

`SELECT  st_geometryFromText(st_astext(st_extent(p.geometry))),<your SRID>)  FROM Pipe p WHERE p.id = ?1`

I hope it works

Comment: I need `st_extent` because it is an aggregate function. In my real use case the query is `WHERE p.id IN ?1` being the parameter a list of IDs and I want the extent of all the involved geometries. I edit my question.

Comment: I edit the second query, with geomfromtext, you have the geometry, and then you can parse

Comment: Same exception (with the two postgis functions also mentioned in it). The casting option doesn't work (`unexpected token: : near line 1, column 29`).

Comment: Look [http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Extent.html] , it shows how to force back into a geometry                                                                                              --Force back into a geometry
 -- and render the extended text representation of that geometry
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(the_geom),2249) as bextent FROM sometable;

Comment: I think that the issue is with spring-data-jpa not recognizing postgis functions. I edit my question.

Comment: And st_boundary instead st_extent?

Comment: Same exception. It's clear that it doesn't like PostGIS functions.